# Adding a function to "Add to cart" button

Tags: magento-1.9, addtocart

I want "add to cart" button to be visible for all visitors, but work just for customers. And when visitors (who didn't login) press "Add to Cart" button i want to show them a popup or redirect them into a cms page which is going to tell them that they need to login to use this function.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a checking to see that user is logged in or not on every **Add to Cart** button.

Like for `listing` page find this lines:

```
<?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
<button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button><br>
<?php else: ?>
<p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
<?php endif; ?>
```

And replace it with:

```
  <?php if(Mage::getModel('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()): ?>
<?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
<button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button><br>
<?php else: ?>
<p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php else: ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $this->getBaseUrl(); ?>cms_page_link" id="fake_addtocart"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></a>
<?php endif; ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery('#fake_addtocart').click(function(){
    alert('Please login to add item to Cart');
    return true;
});
</script>
```

**Here I add a if condition to check that user logged in or not with `Mage::getModel('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()` code.**

This will show user a alert to login then redirect user to cms page.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Let me know that is this worked or not

Comment: Thank you for your answer but code doesn't work. Can you check please?

Comment: on which file you replace this code??

Comment: template/catalog/product/list.phtml  and then the catalog page didnt work properly.

Comment: i update my answer. Check that and let me know

Comment: Still doesn't work...

Comment: what error is comming??

Comment: Half of the category page disappears

Comment: I just test it. And i see that this works perfectly. So i assume that you are doing something wrong

Comment: I tried again and it works fine now.. Thank you so much again..

Comment: You can upvote the answer for all community users

Comment: Anyway welcome to community! Happy learning

Comment: @AsishHira  could you pls help me, in my cms page add to cart not working -> code ->  https://justpaste.it/49eqz

Answer (score 1):

You can check if customer is logged in or not by

```
Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()
```

Then go to addtocart button in addtocart.phtml and in onclick check if user is log in or not and depending on that you can redirect to the page.

```
onclick="<?php  if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) {?>location.href = 'http://notloggedinpage/'<?php }else {?>productAddToCartForm.submit(this)<?php }?>"
```

Then can have any massage on notloggedin page